# redirect link from facebook to website - javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, facebook

I have articles posted on facebook from my website http://juniorgoldreport.com/

the website is made in wordpress, and I've also created a "Welome" landing page where I want most new users to be directed too.

I have no idea where I can find information on how to do this, even after countless efforts of googling.

To give an exact idea of what I' trying to create...

Where someone clicks on an article on facebook, it'll take them to the "welcome" sign up page, then have a link on it to the article that they clicked on. The link would change depending on what article they clicked on so they can be redirected properly.

I know I can just hard code it, and create multiple landing pages with different links in relation to the article posted, but this just seems inefficient.

Does anyone know how to go about doing this?

this is the landing page
http://juniorgoldreport.com/welcome/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using Javascript, as it would be much easier than creating several webpages. At the point in your page where you want a link to be placed, put something like

```
<p id="mynewredirectlink"><a href="default.link">Hey!</a></p>
```

And then at the bottom of your code, add some javascript to resemble this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (document.referrer === "facebooklink.com")//Where did you come from?
    $("#mynewredirectlink").innerHTML = "<a href="theyclickedfromfacebook.link">Hey!</a>"   //Where are you going?
```

Then include the other sites you need, and close it with

```
</script>
```

There may be some sites that have varying parts, like an id, so if you need to, you can use (document.referrer.includes("facebook.com")) instead.

Comment: Thank you! This is along the lines of what I was looking for. I've posted a link to my landing page as well. I do need some extra help if you dont mind. 

The landing page default is has a link to the actual website, so "default.link" would just be my website link I assume. 

I'm not totally sure in the script how it replaces the default link with the article link from the facebook page they clicked on.

For example, my facebook page has currently three different articles. How can I change the link depending on which one they clicked on? (or more then 3 in the future)

Comment: I added a couple comments in the answer to try to explain, but essentially the **document.referrer** will return the URL of the site they came from, telling you where they found the link to your site. Then, the JQuery, looking like **$("#ID").innerHTML =** will change the link to something else. It's like replacing that part of the page with new code. You can change the **<a href>** to whatever link you want.

Comment: I totally get that, that helped a lot. Thank you. I'm starting to really get a grasp of this. Now here's another curve ball that I'm running into in my head. https://www.facebook.com/Junior-Gold-Report-1109199029121549/ is the facebook page. How can I check to see which article is exactly which link considering they're all on the same page?

Comment: I haven't messed around with this very much, but I would suggest using parameters in your URL, such as *yourwebsite.com/landingpage.html?camefrom=article1* Check out this link to see how to use them: http://html.net/tutorials/php/lesson10.php

Comment: It seems like with the URL variables, php is the best route. Luckily, you can embed php in HTML code like the website I showed you exemplifies.

Comment: so in a combination of the URL variables and the script is what I'd be using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112947/discussion-between-jfed-and-robolisk).

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your landing page into a fullscreen modal popup. So every new visitor will see the popup when the visit the site or any article. They can fill the form / they can close it to see the article. There is already several plugin for modal popup / newsletter popup. You just need to do a little bit css to make it full screen.

Comment: JFed gave me a good answer for what I was looking for, although, your solution is excellent as well. It gave me a temp fix until I finish a solid landing page with PHP and all that fun stuff. Thank you!